# Android: How do you make an android toast stay for long

Tags: android, toast

I have an activity in which i'm planing to use a toast message for information. The toast contains a large text, i used this, it is not working.

```
Toast.makeText
(getApplicationContext(), "My Text Goes Here", 20000).show();
```

Comment: This is not possible. Toast are only short or long term. I think long is something like 2 seconds. Use a dialog if your need something longer.

Comment: Toast are only for short notification. If you want to display a long text, use best a DialogBox.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not possible. The last parameter in the makeText method actually expects one of two constants:

```
Toast.LENGTH_LONG
```

and

```
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
```

You cannot influence how long the toast is shown aside from choosing one of these. If you have a long text consider using a dialog like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
builder.setTitle("Title");
builder.setMessage("Long Text...");
builder.setNeutralButton("Ok",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Of course you should not hardcode strings like I did in this example. Consider putting them in the string resources.

Comment: I'll try this, thnx for your help. Can you please post a dialog with just one button to exit the dialog.

Comment: Of course, I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thnx a million, it worked!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can't show your `Toast` longer than the default time which is defined by `Toast.LENGTH_LONG`.

Since you want to show large message then you should use `Dialog` instead of `Taost`.

You can achieve that using `Dialog` as below...

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
dialogBuilder.setTitle("Mesage");
dialogBuilder.setText("Your message...");
dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

The values of `LENGTH_SHORT` and `LENGTH_LONG` are 0 and 1.They are treated as flags rather than actual durations so it is not possible to set the duration to anything other than these values.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about the `Toast` and go for `Dialog`.

Personally I prefer to create a general method (in a separate Java object called as needed) for creating Dialogs, to avoid code duplication.

```
public void showAlert(int title, int message, Activity reportActivity) {
        // Create an alert dialog box
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(reportActivity);
        // Set alert title
        builder.setTitle(title);

        // Set the value for the positive reaction from the user
        // You can also set a listener to call when it is pressed
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null);

        // The message
        builder.setMessage(message);

        // Create the alert dialog and display it
        AlertDialog theAlertDialog = builder.create();
        theAlertDialog.show();
    }
```